# Generic Javascript Image Swap

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a navigation bar where the images should be swapped out on mouseover; normally I use CSS for this but this time I'm trying to figure out javascript. This is what I have right now:

HTML:

```
<li class="bio"><a href="bio.html" onMouseOver="over_bio(this); return true" onMouseOut="up_bio()"><img src="images/nav/bio.jpg" name="bio" /></a></li>
```

Javascript:

```
if (document.images) {
  var bio_up = new Image();
  bio_up.src = "images/nav/bio.jpg";
  var bio_over = new Image();
  bio_over.src = "images/nav/bio-ov.jpg";
}

function over_bio() {
  if (document.images) {
    document["bio"].src = bio_over.src
  }
}

function up_bio() {
  if (document.images) {
    document["bio"].src = bio_up.src
  }
}
```

However, all of the images have names of the form "xyz.jpg" and "xyz-ov.jpg", so I would prefer to just have a generic function that works for every image in the navbar, rather than a separate function for each image.

Comment: FYI you should avoid swapping images on hover as there will almost always be a delay while the new image loads. Ideally you'd want to utilize a background sprite with all the "states" (normal,hover,active) and then you can use JQuery to position the background accordingly to reveal the appropriate state. This allows for all the states to be downloaded by the browser at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work will all image formats as long as the extension is between 2 and 4 characters long IE. png, jpeg, jpg, gif etc.

```
var images = document.getElementById('navbar').getElementsByTagName('img'), i;

for(i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    images[i].onmouseover = function(){
        this.src = this.src.replace(/^(.*)(\.\w{2,4})$/, '$1'+'-ov'+'$2');
    }

    images[i].onmouseout = function(){
        this.src = this.src.replace(/^(.*)-ov(\.\w{2,4})$/, '$1'+'$2');
    }
}
```

Comment: The onmouseout function assumes there are no occurrences of -ov elsewhere in the URL.  Perhaps a safe assumption, perhaps not.

Comment: An example of this with annoying alert boxes telling you every time an img src changes: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/duKND/3/

Comment: @jfriend00 I updated it to be safe from that assumption, although I think that is a reasonably safe assumption to make :)

Comment: I love seeing how many different ways there are to attack a fairly simple problem like this.

Comment: @jfriend00 Besides, it's not much different that karims assumption that the images aren't hosted on `www.jpgs.domain.com`

Comment: @jfriend00 Yeah, you learn a lot of different coding styles from using Stack Overflow :)

Comment: Does this require editing the HTML at all? I tried replacing my JS with both this code and the code above (no, not at the same time) and neither worked for me, so I assume I'm doing something wrong (I'm totally new to JavaScript)

Comment: @William, I wrote the code to only affect images inside an element with id="navbar". See jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/duKND/3 Your HTML will look like that. No need for `onmouseover` or `onmouseout` or `<a>` tags around your `<img>` tags. Just make sure the images you want it do function on are wrapped in an element with id="navbar"

Comment: @William if you'd prefer to not change anything to have id="navbar" you could also remove `document.getElementById('navbar').` from the first line of the code, but that will turn every image on your page into a rollover image.

Comment: Yeah, I already had them inside a navbar (well, it was a class, but I changed it to an ID when I read your code). I do need the a tags, since these are navigation links :-)

Comment: @William Haha yes, then of course you need them :) You just don't need their onmouseover and onmouseout attributes. If you can't get it working, play around with this: http://jsfiddle.net/Paulpro/duKND/3/ Try putting the absolute url for your own image in that imgs src. You can see the roll over effect working with the current image, but it just disappears because `http://www.sitemakershosting.com/images/50x50-ov.gif` doesn't exist. Once you have it working in js-fiddle you should be able to move it to your really website. Do you know how to use jsfiddle?

Comment: I don't, but I'll look into it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A quick-fire solution which should be robust enough provided all your images are of the same type:

```
$("li.bio a").hover(function() {
    var $img = $(this).find("img");
    $img[0].src = $img[0].src.replace(".jpg", "") + "-ov.jpg";
}, function() {
    var $img = $(this).find("img");
    $img[0].src = $img[0].src.replace("-ov.jpg", "") + ".jpg";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea in plain javascript (no jQuery):

```
function onMouseOverSwap(e) {
   e.src = e.src.replace(/\.jpg$/", "-ov.jpg");    // add -ov onto end
}

function onMouseOutSwap(e) {
    e.src = e.src.replace(/(-ov)+\.jpg$/, ".jpg");  // remove -ov
}
```